# Continue Reading have to go post top

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

If I click 'Continue Reading' link, with *more* option in **wordpress**, It's going to specific place. See [Link](http://www.fndplan.com/uses-facts-green-tea-benefits/#more-67).

But I need to go that post's top or page's top.
What to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_more_link_scroll( $link ) {
  $link = preg_replace( '|#more-[0-9]+|', '', $link );
  return $link;
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'remove_more_link_scroll' );
```

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Prevent_Page_Scroll_When_Clicking_the_More_Link